# j_spring_security_check not available. Please help with Spring3 login

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am trying to write something in Spring3 with Security.  I was trying to use the default login screen which everyone says Spring will display for you.  but after two days of trying and getting the error:

> /spring-security-login not found

I give up and changed my code to:

```
<http  auto-config="true"> 
<intercept-url pattern="/friends/**" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN"  />
<form-login login-page="/login.jsp" 
        default-target-url="/friends/add.html"
        authentication-failure-url="/login.jsp?authfailed=true" />
</http>
```

and I added the `login.jsp` to my project which I think I made right.  Now I am getting this error:

> HTTP Status 404 - /MySpring/j_spring_security_check
>   message /MySpring/j_spring_security_check
>   description The requested resource (/MySpring/j_spring_security_check) is not available.

Answer (score 0):

add this in your web.xml

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```